# How to do the sum of the values in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

//What I'm trying to do is count the sum of the data in this array.

```
const storage = [
  { data: '1', status: '0' },
  { data: '2', status: '0' },
  { data: '3', status: '0' },
  { data: '4', status: '0' },
  { data: '5', status: '0' },
  { data: '6', status: '0' },
  { data: '7', status: '1' },
];
```

Comment: Count the sum how?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: have an initial variable at 0 and use a for loop and keep adding to the variable

Comment: let sum = storage.reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b.data), 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` here, see more info about [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const storage = [{
    data: '1',
    status: '0'
  },
  {
    data: '2',
    status: '0'
  },
  {
    data: '3',
    status: '0'
  },
  {
    data: '4',
    status: '0'
  },
  {
    data: '5',
    status: '0'
  },
  {
    data: '6',
    status: '0'
  },
  {
    data: '7',
    status: '1'
  },
];


const sum = storage.reduce((acc, value) => acc + Number(value.data), 0);

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [a simple loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) - no need to get snarled up with `reduce`.

(Just make sure you coerce the string value to a `Number` when you're doing the addition.)

```js
const storage=[{data:"1",status:"0"},{data:"2",status:"0"},{data:"3",status:"0"},{data:"4",status:"0"},{data:"5",status:"0"},{data:"6",status:"0"},{data:"7",status:"1"}];

let sum = 0;

for (const obj of storage) {
  sum += Number(obj.data);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
const total = storage.map(({data}) => Number(data)).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
```

So, first, lets get an array of numbers, which is de first part:

```
storage.map(({data}) => Number(data))
```

This will get the data by destructuring from each of the elements, or you can write it like so:

```
storage.map((item) => Number(item.data))
```

Then we'll reduce the list by adding all the items together:

```
list.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
```

This means, start with 0, then foreach element, add it to the result. This will give you the total.

Comment: Please don't code dump and expect people (especially people new to coding) to work this out without commentary/links to documentation.

Comment: I'll throw in some comments for you! Hopefully this explains it a bit better